# $item->getSku() and $item->getProduct()->getSku() return different values. Why?

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, orders, collection

**Edit:** originally this question was just about `sales/order` objects but I've found an identical problem with `sales/quote` objects too, so I'm editing it to include that.

I also added a **TL;DR** at the bottom which might be clearer for some people.

---

I'm trying to get information on the items from an order/quote, but have found that using `$item->getSku()` is not very intuitive.

It always returns the child SKU, even if I'm running it inside a `getAllVisibleItems()` loop (as opposed to just `getAllItems()`).

The SKU it returns is different from `$item->getProduct()->getSku()`.

When called inside `getAllVisibleItems()` I would expect `$item->getSku()` to return the parent product's SKU and not the child SKU (because the parent is the one which is *visible*).

**Edit:** I've discovered an even more problematic issue. When I loop on a `sales/quote` collection instead of `sales/order`, the `$item->getProduct()->getSku()` call doesn't even return the correct (parent) SKU. It still returns the child-level SKU which is wrong. In order to get the correct parent-level SKU, I have to actually fully load the product (see the second block of code below).

Why is this happening?

Here's my code:

#### For sales/order collections:

```
<?php

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId("123456");

foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $orderItem) {
    echo "Item SKU =>    " . $orderItem->getSku();
    echo "Product SKU => " . $orderItem->getProduct()->getSku();
}

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
    echo "Item SKU =>    " . $orderItem->getSku();
    echo "Product SKU => " . $orderItem->getProduct()->getSku();
}

// Output

getAllVisibleItems:
Item SKU    => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Parent product - misleading item SKU
Product SKU => SHOE1

Item SKU    => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Parent product - misleading item SKU
Product SKU => SHOE2       

getAllItems:
Item SKU    => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Parent product - misleading item SKU
Product SKU => SHOE1       

Item SKU    => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Child product - correct item SKU
Product SKU => SHOE1-SIZE5

Item SKU    => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Parent product - misleading item SKU
Product SKU => SHOE2

Item SKU    => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Child product - correct item SKU
Product SKU => SHOE2-SIZE4
```

#### For sales/quote collections:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load("98765");

foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quoteItem) {
    echo "Item SKU                 => " . $quoteItem->getSku();
    echo "Product SKU              => " . $quoteItem->getProduct()->getSku();
    echo "Fully Loaded Product SKU => " . Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($quoteItem->getProduct()->getId())->getSku();
}

foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
    echo "Item SKU                 => " . $quoteItem->getSku();
    echo "Product SKU              => " . $quoteItem->getProduct()->getSku();
    echo "Fully Loaded Product SKU => " . Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($quoteItem->getProduct()->getId())->getSku();
}

// Output

getAllVisibleItems:
Item SKU                 => SHOE1-SIZE5 // The child SKU (wrong)
Product SKU              => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Different behaviour than sales/order object
Fully Loaded Product SKU => SHOE1       // The parent SKU (correct)

Item SKU                 => SHOE2-SIZE4 // The child SKU (wrong)
Product SKU              => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Different behaviour than sales/order object
Fully Loaded Product SKU => SHOE2       // The parent SKU (correct)

getAllItems:
Item SKU                 => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Parent product - misleading item SKU
Product SKU              => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Misleading
Fully Loaded Product SKU => SHOE2       // Correct

Item SKU                 => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Child product - correct item SKU
Product SKU              => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Correct
Fully Loaded Product SKU => SHOE1-SIZE5 // Correct

Item SKU                 => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Parent product - misleading item SKU
Product SKU              => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Misleading
Fully Loaded Product SKU => SHOE2       // Correct

Item SKU                 => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Child product - correct item SKU
Product SKU              => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Correct
Fully Loaded Product SKU => SHOE2-SIZE4 // Correct
```

#### TL;DR

The TL;DR of this post is: **These two SKUs come out different. Why?**

```
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {

    // These two SKUs are different. Why?
    echo $cartItem->getProduct()->getSku();
    echo Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($cartItem->getProduct()->getId())->getSku();

}
```

Comment: The reason for this might be that `$item->getSku()` gets the SKU stored at the time when the order/quote was created. `$item->getProduct()->getSku()` first loads the product and then gets the SKU from that object, this could be a different one than the one in the `$item` when it was changed after the product was edited for example.

Comment: See my TL;DR for an example of where `$item->getProduct()` returns the wrong SKU, but `$item->getProduct->getId()` returns the correct ID.

Comment: Are you asking if the dash in the SKU is incorrect?

Comment: @philwinkle: No, the problem is that the SKU is only correct if you re-load the product and then call `getSku()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's an intended behaviour (see https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php#L832), possibly for display purposes, but I agree with you: for fashion products this is mostly the *wrong* expected behaviour.

It is very easy to get around that, though: just call

```
 $item->getProduct()->getData('sku')
```

instead of `$item->getProduct()->getSku()`. You should definitely avoid to reload the product during cart and order operations, since it's not needed and it might lead to performance issues.

Comment: You know, I had assumed that `getSku` was a magic "getter" function which basically acted as an alias for `getData("sku")`. I should have known better. Thanks.